# Record time when column update for first time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

1. In SQL Server 2005, I want to record the current time when the `online` column changes to `1` from `0` for the first time as soon as a user logs in.  The `online` column gets updated every 5-10 minutes (that means, my web app updates `online` column to `1` for every 5-10 minutes until a user is logged in to website).  I want to record time only for the first time the column changes to `1`.
2. I have to update the `reputation` column for every one hour from the time recorded by step 1 above until the same user stays logged in and stop updating `reputation` as soon as `online` changes to `0`

How to do that? I have very thin knowledge about building queries and triggers.

Answer (score 0):

personally I would tackle this by adding a second bit column next to online for timerecorded or something along those lines.

Basically the logic would look like this.

```
Update users set online = 1

update users set onlinesince = getdate()
where online = 1 and timerecorded = 0

update users set reputation = reputation + 1
where online = 1 and timerecorded = 1
```

When you get around to setting online = 0 just make sure you set both flags.